# How to add a carriage / line feed in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a field in SSRS report which comes from the database. It can have 2 sentences, 3 or any number based on different conditions. But if there is space in the sentence it needs to show as a new paragraph.  Wherever there is a CRLF it should start with next line.

e.g.

> Today is a sunny day. I need to go out.
>
> I will go to see a movie.

```
=iif(Fields!Details.Value <> "", Fields!Details.Value & vbcrlf , "")
```

The expected result is:

> Today is a sunny day. I need to go out.
>
> I will go to see a movie.

But the output I am getting is:

> Today is a sunny day. I need to go out.I will go to see a movie.

Comment: why is the sentence splitting on the second dot and not the first? You can also replace your "." with a <br/> and then make the placeholder property a HTML markup type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your problem based on the examples because you're saying the any time there's a space between sentences, there should be a line break.  However, you're only breaking the third sentence to a new line when there's another sentence that should have a line break by your requirement.

However, if your goal is to add a line break between all sentence breaks, I suggest using `Replace`.  What I suggest is to find any period followed by a space and replace that with a period and a line break such as the following expression.

```
=Replace(Fields!Details.Value, ". ", ". " & vbcrlf)
```

or...

```
=Replace(Fields!Details.Value, ". ", ". " & Chr(13))
```

Comment: you have some misplaced quotes in your answer.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Maybe my eyes are starting to go but I can't see it.. Feel free to edit?

Comment: This will result in 3 lines rather than 2. From the question, it seems to suggest there is a line feed or carriage return in the input between the second and third lines which isn't being diplayed correctly. In this case, the `Replace` should be on `chr(10)` (line feed) or `chr(13)` (carriage return) rather than `". "`.